# Cannot start MOC - "No valid sound driver found" in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, moc

I had to hard-reboot my Raspberry Pi (unplug the power) running Ubuntu Server 20.04 and since then I cannot run the console music player`mocp` anymore.
The program runs through the initialization of OSS and ALSA drivers, then fails with the message `FATAL_ERROR: No valid sound driver!`

I have tried purging the package (via `apt-get purge mocp`) and reinstalling it, but the error message remains. Googling around this question brings up a few very old threads ([here](https://moc.daper.net/node/485) and [here](http://moc.daper.net/node/278)) on MOC's own discussion boards, suggesting this to be either an ALSA issue or with the sound card, but I'm not sure about this since when I run `alsamixer` it starts and I can do things like change the volume of it. Plus, if run other programs that use audio like mpg123 the audio is fine.

Detailed error log extracted with `mocp -F` is shown below, sorry if it's a little verbose. Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Many thanks!

```
Aug 31 15:34:23.139072: main.c:1191 main(): This is Music On Console (version 2.6-alpha3)
Aug 31 15:34:23.139216: main.c:1195 main(): Configured: '--build=arm-linux-gnueabihf' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' 'build_alias=arm-linux-gnueabihf' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/moc-NiZ4Xl/moc-2.6.0~svn-r2994=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -pedantic' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/moc-NiZ4Xl/moc-2.6.0~svn-r2994=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
Aug 31 15:34:23.139240: main.c:1205 main(): Running on: Linux 5.4.0-1015-raspi armv7l
Aug 31 15:34:23.140180: main.c:1157 log_command_line(): mocp -F 
Aug 31 15:34:23.140265: main.c:1171 log_popt_command_line(): mocp --foreground 
Aug 31 15:34:23.159074: decoder.c:700 load_plugins(): Loaded 11 decoders: aac flac modplug mp3 musepack opus sidplay2 sndfile speex vorbis wavpack
Aug 31 15:34:23.159160: server.c:360 server_init(): Starting MOC Server
Aug 31 15:34:23.159210: log.c:233 log_init_stream(): Writing log to: stdout
Aug 31 15:34:23.159384: server.c:300 log_process_stack_size(): Process's stack size: 8388608
Aug 31 15:34:23.159402: server.c:317 log_pthread_stack_size(): PThread's stack size: 8388608
Trying JACK...
Aug 31 15:34:23.160789: jack.c:121 error_cb(): ERROR: JACK: Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Aug 31 15:34:23.160809: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.160847: jack.c:121 error_cb(): ERROR: JACK: Cannot connect to server request channel
Aug 31 15:34:23.160861: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.163010: jack.c:121 error_cb(): ERROR: JACK: jack server is not running or cannot be started
Aug 31 15:34:23.163028: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.163298: jack.c:121 error_cb(): ERROR: JACK: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Aug 31 15:34:23.163317: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.163332: jack.c:121 error_cb(): ERROR: JACK: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Aug 31 15:34:23.163344: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.163369: jack.c:148 moc_jack_init(): ERROR: jack_client_open() failed, status = 0x11
Aug 31 15:34:23.163381: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.163393: jack.c:150 moc_jack_init(): ERROR: Unable to connect to JACK server
Aug 31 15:34:23.163404: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Trying ALSA...
Aug 31 15:34:23.163423: alsa.c:477 alsa_init(): Initialising ALSA device: default
Aug 31 15:34:23.165678: alsa.c:365 alsa_init_mixer_channel(): ERROR: Can't find mixer PCM
Aug 31 15:34:23.165710: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.165733: alsa.c:365 alsa_init_mixer_channel(): ERROR: Can't find mixer Master
Aug 31 15:34:23.165751: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Trying OSS...
Aug 31 15:34:23.165829: oss.c:206 oss_init(): ERROR: Can't open mixer device /dev/mixer: No such file or directory
Aug 31 15:34:23.165851: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.165899: oss.c:71 open_dev(): ERROR: Can't open /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
Aug 31 15:34:23.165918: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.165939: oss.c:87 set_capabilities(): ERROR: Can't open the device.
Aug 31 15:34:23.165956: server.c:672 add_event_all(): No events have been added because there are no clients
Aug 31 15:34:23.166034: audio.c:926 find_working_driver(): FATAL ERROR: No valid sound driver!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues getting `mocp` running on my RPi, too.

There were several issues:

- my user wasn't in the `audio` group, thus I had to use sudo to run `amixer`. Adding my user to that group solved that problem.
- in my config (`~/.moc/config`, which was a copy from `/usr/share/doc/moc/examples/config.example`) the ALSA settings were `PCM` and `Master`.
- when running with `sudo`, this settings file in my user-folder was ignored
- when using `-C` or `--config` the config-file was "insecure" because I ran as sudo and the config file belonged to my user and not to root.
- when I ran `amixer` it showed `Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0`
- once I set the ALSA Settings in the moc config to use `Headphone` instead of `Master` or `PCM`, it started to work

Comment: Hey thanks for the insight. I checked again actually after so long without using mocp and it looks like the issue solved itself. Strangely, I am already in the `audio` group, and it's root that can't run the command now (go figure!). But this gave me good insights for what to try next time.